# How do I change the order of items in a string?

Tags: python

I have to take a string with info about a person in the format  LAST, FIRST (BIRTH-DEATH) to first, last, age. i.e. print(biotoage("Last, First (1912-1954)")) turns into First Last, 42.

This is the code I currently have:

```
def bio_to_age(bio: str) -> str:
count = 0
# loop for search each index
for i in range(0, len(bio)):
    # Check each char
    # is comma or not
    if bio[i] == ",":
        count += 0
firstName = bio[0:count]
lastName = bio[count:]
numAge = 2022-1945
return firstName, lastName, numAge
```

Its not working to count the first and last names, which are case sensitive, and I do not know how to do the year either.

example: print(bio_to_age("Adle, Leo (1945-)"))
should be  Leo Adle, 77
Thank you!

EDIT I found out I also need to have it work for if the person has a middle name as well, so print(bio_to_age("Allie Jackie, Allegra (1945-)"))
would bell Allegra Allie Jackie, 77

Comment: Please, give us some examples of input info and result you want to get

Comment: split, calculate age, reassemble

Comment: The input is `Adle, Leo (1945)` or `Adle, Leo, 1945` ?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1):

It's much easier to do this using the `split` function. Assuming that there are no extraneous spaces, we could do the following.

```
def bio_to_age(bio: str) -> str:
    current_yr = 2022
    last,first,yrs = bio.split() # split string by spaces
    last = last[:-1]             # remove comma at end of first segment
    yrs = yrs[1:-1]              # remove lead and closing parentheses
    start,end = yrs.split('-')   # split years segment by "-"
    start = int(start)
    if end == '':                # if no death year is given
        end = current_yr
    else:                        # if death year is given
        end = int(end)
    return f"{first} {last}, {end - start}"

print(bio_to_age("Adle, Leo (1945-)"))
print(bio_to_age("Adle, Leo (1945-2000)"))
```

The resulting outputs are `Leo Adle, 77` and `Leo Adle, 55`.

---

Here's a version that accounts for an optional middle name

```
def bio_to_age(bio):
    tokens = bio.split() # split string by spaces
    if len(tokens) == 3:
        last,first,yrs = tokens
    else:
        mid,last,first,yrs = tokens 
    last = last[:-1]
    yrs = yrs[1:-1]              # remove lead and closing parentheses
    start,end = yrs.split('-')      # split years segment by "-"
    start = int(start)
    if end == '':
        end = 2022
    else:
        end = int(end)
    if len(tokens) == 3:
        return f"{first} {last}, {end - start}"
    return f"{first} {mid} {last}, {end - start}"

print(bio_to_age("Adle, Leo (1945-)"))
print(bio_to_age("Adle, Leo (1945-2000)"))
print(bio_to_age("Allie Jackie, Allegra (1945-)"))
```

Comment: Thank you! How would that work if there were a middle name that needed to be printed as well?

Comment: @grom See my latest edit

Comment: I tried that, but for some reason it always cuts off one letter of the name and adds an extra comma

Comment: @grom Looks like I misunderstood the order of the names, try it now

Comment: Sorry, turns out theres one more requiement I did not know of, I also have to print out Abel, Niels Henrik (1802-1829) without an excess comma. It is pretty convoluted to me.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
def bio_to_age(bio: str) -> str:
    inf = ''
    ans = []

    for i in bio:
        if i.isalnum():
            inf += i
        else:
            if inf != '':
                ans.append(inf)
                inf = ''
            else:
                continue
    ans.append(inf)

    if len(ans) == 4:
        return(f"{ans[1]} {ans[0]}, {int(ans[3]) - int(ans[2])}")
    else:
        return(f"{ans[1]} {ans[0]}, {2022 - int(ans[2])}")
```

```
print(bio_to_age("Adle, Leo (1945-)"))
# output - Leo Adle, 77
```

Answer (score 0):

Regular expressions will be helpful for extracting text in different fixed formats.

```
import re
import datetime

def biotoage(input_str : str) -> str:
    """
    Specific preprocessing code for a highly rigid fixed format.

        Last, First (start_year-end_year) --> First Last, (approx_age)

    Note: approx_age will not be exact as only calculating with years
    """
    
    # Extract dates using regex
    year_start = re.search(string=input_str, pattern="(?<=\()(.*)(-)")[0][:-1]
    year_end = re.search(string=input_str, pattern="(-)(.*)(\))")[0][1:-1]

    if year_end == '':

        year_end = datetime.datetime.today().year

    approx_age = int(year_end) - int(year_start)

    # Regex pattern for start and end name
    names = re.search(string=input_str, pattern="(.*)(\()")[0][:-1]

    # Remove whitespace in names
    names = names.replace(" ", "")

    # Split names by comma
    split = names.split(",")
    
    # Extract first and last name
    last_name = split[0]
    first_name = split[1]

    output = f"{first_name} {last_name}, {approx_age}"

    return output
```

It's worth noting that the "age" that you're calculating will not be exact:

- 31 Dec 2001 to 1 Jan 2022 is 1 day, but is 1 "year" based on the years alone
- 31 Dec 2001 to 1 Jan 2003 is 1 year, 1 day but is 2 "years" based on the years alone

With the above, you can then run:

```
biotoage(input_str="Last, First (1912-1954)")
```

Which will give:

```
'First Last, 42'
```

Answer (score 0):

Unpack the input using `split`, use `str.removeprefix('(')` and `str.removesuffix(')')` to remove '`( )`' in `years` then use `str.split('-')`. Add `datetime` for adaptability for current year. Check if `pass_away` value exist, if not return `datetime.today().year`. Lastly, return `first_name`, `last_name`, and calculated age in `f-string`.

```
from datetime import datetime

def bio_to_age(bio: str) -> str:
    last_name, first_name, years = bio.split()
    born, pass_away = years.removeprefix('(').removesuffix(')').split('-')
    pass_away = datetime.today().year if not pass_away else pass_away
    return f'{first_name} {last_name} {int(pass_away) - int(born)}'

print(bio_to_age("Adle, Leo (1945-)"))
print(bio_to_age("Adle, Leo (1945-1995)"))

# Leo Adle, 77
# Leo Adle, 50
```